# assigning value in python dict (copy vs reference)

Tags: python, reference

I understand that in python every thing, be it a number, string, dict or anything is an object. The variable name simply points to the object in the memory. Now according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438938/python-copy-through-assignment),

`>> a_dict = b_dict = c_dict = {}`

This creates an empty dictionary and all the variables point to this dict object. So, changing any one would be reflected in the other variables.

```
>> a_dict["key"] = "value" #say
>> print a_dict
>> print b_dict
>> print c_dict
```

would give

```
{'key': value}
{'key': value}
{'key': value}
```

I had understood the concept of variables pointing to objects, so this seems fair enough.

Now even though it might be weird, since its such a basic statement, why does this happen ?

```
>> a = b = c = 1
>> a += 1
>> print a, b, c
2, 1, 1   # and not 2, 2, 2
```

**First part of question:** Why isn't the same concept applied here ?

Actually this doubt came up when I was trying to search for a solution for this:

```
>> a_dict = {}
>> some_var = "old_value"
>> a_dict['key'] = some_var
>> some_var = "new_value"
>> print a_dict
{'key': 'old_value'}  # and not {'key': 'new_value'}
```

This seemed counter-intuitive since I had always assumed that I am telling the dictionary to hold the variable, and changing the object that the variable was pointing to would obviously reflect in the dictionary. But this seems to me as if the value is being copied, not referenced. **This was the second thing I didn't understand.**

Moving on, i tried something else

```
>> class some_class(object):
..    def __init__(self):
..        self.var = "old_value"
>> some_object = some_class()
>> a_dict = {}
>> a_dict['key'] = some_object
>> some_object.var = "new_value"
>> print a_dict['key'].var
"new_value"    # even though this was what i wanted and expected, it conflicts with the output in the previous code
```

Now, over here, obviously it was being referenced. These contradictions has left me squacking at the unpredictable nature of python, even though I still love it, owing to the fact I don't know any other language well enough :p . Even though I'd always imagined that assignments lead to reference of the object, however these 2 cases are conflicting. **So this is my final doubt** . I understand that it might be one those python  *gotcha's* . Please educate me.

Comment: `every thing, be it a number, string, dict or anything is an object` This is not true. Numbers and strings are (in essence) passed by value. (I'm sure someone will correct me with the latest Python terminology).

Comment: In my opinion, everything is an object. For example, strings have the method join. ' '.join([1,2,3]) would give '1 2 3'. So they have to be objects. Also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865911/is-everything-an-object-in-python-like-ruby) shows the fact.

Comment: Okay, yes, they are certainly objects. But go ahead and try passing an `int` to a function and changing it. The value outside the function does not change. Same thing with a string. That was my point.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes, you are correct. Isn't that because a new int/string is created local to the method/function. Hmm.. but passing an object and changing its attributes reflects in the global object. What is the meaning of this..?? So, why this discrepency ? why are int/strings copied whereas objects are passed as references ?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I figured it out. Even parameters are passed as references. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13608959/2851353). On changing the value of a parameter passed to the method, the new value object is binded to the local variable (overwriting the passed reference), leaving the original binding(original variable-> original value) intact.

Comment: In reality, this is wrong : Everything is passed by value, but in many cases (generaly, for complex objects, the passed value is a reference to the object., this is why, for simple objects, you do no have the same behavior.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're wrestling with 2 different things here.  The first is the idea of *mutability* vs. *immutability*.  In python, `str`, `int`, `tuple` are some of the builtin immutable types compared to `list`, `dict` (and others) which are mutable types.  *immutable* objects are ones which cannot be changed once they are created.  So, in your example:

```
a = b = c = 1
```

After that line, all `a`, `b` and `c` refer to the same integer in memory (you can check by printing their respecitve `id`'s and noting that they are the same).  However, when you do:

```
a += 1
```

`a` now refers to a new (different) integer at a different memory location.  Note that as a convention, `+=` should return a new instance of something if the type is immutable.  If the type is *mutable*, it should change the object in place and return it.  I explain some of the more gory detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15376520/748858).

---

For the second part, you're trying to figure out how python's identifiers work.  The way that I think of it is this... when you write a statement:

```
name = something
```

The right hand side is evaluated into some object (an integer, string, ...).  That object is then given the name on the left hand side<sup>1</sup>.  When a name is on the right hand side, the corresponding object is automatically "looked up" and substituted for the name in the calculation.  Note that in this framework, assignment doesn't care if anything had that name before -- it simply overwrites the old value with the new one.  Objects which were previously constructed using that name don't see any changes -- either.  They've already been created -- keeping references to the objects themselves, not the names.  So:

```
a = "foo"  # `a` is the name of the string "foo" 
b = {"bar": a}  # evaluate the new dictionary and name it `b`.  `a` is looked up and returns "foo" in this calculation
a = "bar"  # give the object "bar" the name `a` irrespecitve of what previously had that name
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>I'm glossing over a few details here for simplicity -- e.g. what happens when you assign to a list element:  `lst[idx] = some_value * some_other_value`.</sup>

Comment: `str, int, tuple are some of the builtin immutable types => copy by value`. Recalling this sentence solves everything.

Comment: My understanding in C terms: _immutable_ object is "passed by value", _mutable_ object is "passed by reference". By the way, what you describe in the first part of the answer is an example of RCU.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `+=` can be interpreted as `a = a + 1`, which rebinds the variable `a` to the value `a + 1`, that is, `2`.

Similarly, `some_var = "new_value"` rebinds the variable and the object is not changed, so the key, value pair in the dictionary still points to that object.

In your last example, you are not rebinding, but mutating the object, so the value is changed in the dictionary.