# Why do changes to a nested dict inside dict2 affect dict1?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, mutability

I don't understand these cases:

```
content = {'a': {'v': 1}, 'b': {'v': 2}}
d1 = {'k1': {}}
d2 = {'k2': {}}
d1['k1'].update(content)
print(d1)
content['a']['v'] = 3
content['b']['v'] = 4
d2['k2'].update(content)
print(d2)
print(d1)
>>> {'k1': {'a': {'v': 1}, 'b': {'v': 2}}}
>>> {'k2': {'a': {'v': 3}, 'b': {'v': 4}}}
>>> {'k1': {'a': {'v': 3}, 'b': {'v': 4}}}
```

In the case above the content of d1 is changed after the variable *content* is updated.

```
content = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
d1 = {'k1': {}}
d2 = {'k2': {}}
d1['k1'].update(content)
print(d1)
content['a'] = 3
content['b'] = 4
d2['k2'].update(content)
print(d2)
print(d1)
>>> {'k1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
>>> {'k2': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}}
>>> {'k1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
```

However in this case d1 is **not** altered even if the variable *content* was changed. I don't understand why... any idea?

Comment: I assume all these upvotes but no comments/answers are because people also think this is strange behavior. :P

Comment: @MateenUlhaq It's not, it has to to with the fact that `dict` is mutable object and `int` is immutable. This makes python handle them differently. Similar thing would happen if content was a `list` (mutable).

Comment: Isn't the second example mutating a dictionary (`content`) as well?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq No, in first example keys point to `dict` and in second they point to an `int`. What makes this confusing is the nested nature of these dictionaries but nonetheless, in the background, everything consists from a bunch of pointers that get resolved once called.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq If I were good at explaining this I'd post an answer :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852480/assigning-value-in-python-dict-copy-vs-reference

Answer (score 7):

see [shallow vs deep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) copy.

The copy here is a shallow copy so the first level entries are copies but the nested structures are references.

> - A **shallow copy** constructs a new compound object and then (to the    extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects
>     found in    the original.
> - A **deep copy** constructs a new compound object and then,    recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the
>     original.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates.

Comment: I voted to close for what its worth.

Answer (score 2):

The key difference between your two snippets is that `content['a']['v'] = 3` is a completely different operation than `content['a'] = 3`. In the first case, you're *modifying* the inner dictionary by changing its `v` key. In the latter case, you're *replacing* the value in the dictionary without *modifying* it.

It's confusing when everything's a dictionary, so let's replace the dictionaries with variables and instances of a class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

# these two variables are represent your `content` dict
a = Person('Andy')  # this variable represents `{'v': 1}`
b = Person('Belle')  # this variable represents `{'v': 2}`

# the equivalent of `d1['k1'].update(content)` is a simple assignment
k1_a = a

# and the equivalent of `content['a']['v'] = 3` is changing a's name
a.name = 'Aaron'

# because k1_a and a are the same Person instance, this is reflected in k1_a:
print(k1_a.name)  # output: Aaron
```

The key points to note here are that

1. `k1_a = a` doesn't make a copy of the Person; similar to how `d1['k1'].update(content)` doesn't make a copy of the `{'v': 1}` dict.
2. `a.name = 'Aaron'` *modifies* the Person; similar to how `content['a']['v'] = 3` modifies the inner dict.

The equivalent of your 2nd snippet looks like this:

```
a = 'Andy'
b = 'Belle'

k1_a = a

a = 'Aaron'

print(k1_a)  # output: Andy
```

This time, no object is ever *modified*. All we're doing is overwriting the value of the `a` variable, exactly how `content['a'] = 3` overwrites the value of the `a` key in your dict.

---

If you don't want the changes in the inner dicts to be reflected in other dicts, you have to copy them with [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
import copy

content = {'a': {'v': 1}, 'b': {'v': 2}}
d1 = {'k1': {}}
d2 = {'k2': {}}
d1['k1'].update(copy.deepcopy(content))
print(d1)
content['a']['v'] = 3
content['b']['v'] = 4
d2['k2'].update(copy.deepcopy(content))
print(d2)
print(d1)

# output:
# {'k1': {'a': {'v': 1}, 'b': {'v': 2}}}
# {'k2': {'a': {'v': 3}, 'b': {'v': 4}}}
# {'k1': {'a': {'v': 1}, 'b': {'v': 2}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we replace the `update()` with a simple assignment:

```
# d1['k1'].update(content)
d1['k1'] = content
```

We get:

```
{'k1': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
{'k2': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}}
{'k1': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}}
```

(Which is different from what `update` does in your example.) This is because `update` accepts an iterable (e.g. a dictionary) and copies the key value pairs *inside*. It's equivalent to doing:

```
d1['k1'] = {k: v for k, v in content.items()}
```

And of course, the `int` values are immutables and so their reassignment does not affect the original.