# dictionaries link

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm new to dictionaries and have found the following to be very confusing.

```
resume = [{'name': 'New', 'value1': 'dfgdf'}, {'name': 'garry', 'value1': 'hhhhhh'}]
current = resume[0]
current['name'] = '24/7 link was not requested...'
print(resume)
```

**Returns:**

```
[{'name': '24/7 link was not requested...', 'value1': 'dfgdf'}, {'name': 'garry', 'value1': 'hhhhhh'}]
```

Why is this happening when a permanent/continuous link between `resume` and `current` was **not requested**? ...... and how can I change this so that `current['name']` will update to the new/requested string value and **not resume**.

Comment: But current *is* the first dictionary in resume.

Comment: yes it is, but when i change the values in `current` with `current['name']` ... the value in `resume` should not change. I did not ask for that.

Comment: Is the issue that you don't want to modify the first element in `resume`? If so, you can do `current = resume[0].copy()` to get a copy of the first element instead. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852480/assigning-value-in-python-dict-copy-vs-reference)

Comment: I would also suggest reading about it in here: https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/

Comment: @Rhys yes, you **did** ask for that. Please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html And this has nothing to do with dictionaries, this is how assignment works for *all objects in Python*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
current = resume[0]
```

to

```
current = resume[0].copy()
```

This should create a new dictionary object.

Comment: thanks for this, I'll test it in a little while. Lists can do this without `.copy()` ... what purpose does it serve to include this link by default =/

Comment: No, lists have the *same* behaviour. Read the link that juanpa posted.

Comment: @Rhys no, **everything in Python works like this**.

Comment: wow, you're right. I'd never seen that before

Comment: I'll mark this as correct. Works for lists and dictionaries. for the record it drove me crazy. it adds complexity to basic instructions