# Change the Global value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a global variable called "**result**"  and trying to change this value by calling a function .

```
import sys 

def increment_result(a):
    for i in range(0,3):
        a += 1

result = 0
increment_result(result)
print(result)
```

But the result value is zero but expecting the result value to be 3.How can I change this global variable by using Pass by Reference in Python.

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to change global variable, return the changed value and reassign the return value back to the variable from the caller:

```
import sys 

def increment_result(a):
    for i in range(0,3):
        a += 1
    return a

result = 0
result = increment_result(result)
print(result)
```

If you really want to change global variable, you need to declare it using `global` statement:

```
def increment_result(a):
    global result  # <-- to access the global variable
    for i in range(0,3):
        a += 1
    result = a
```

Comment: This question possible duplicate of [Python: How do I pass a string by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608919/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-by-reference)

Comment: @McGrady, voted to close.