# Recursively reverse a list in place

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

For the below code, even though `reverse(s)` returns the reversed string, the string itself is not reversed.

```
s = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
def reverse(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s;
    temp = s[0]
    s = reverse(s[1:])
    s.append(temp)
    return s

print(reverse(s))
print(s)
```

Output

```
['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h'] #reverse(s)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'] #s
```

As per this, [Python: How do I pass a string by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608919/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-by-reference). I understand i need to set `s= reverse(s)` and then the list gets reversed and this works alright.

But why is `s` getting reversed for this one?

```
s = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
def reverse(s, index):
    if index >= len(s) or len(s) == 0:
        return
    reverse(s, index + 1)
    s.insert((len(s) - 1 - index), s.pop())


reverse(s, 0)
print(s)
```

Output

```
['o', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
```

While debugging I have found out that for the first piece of code when the handle comes back to the print statement, `s` becomes the original list, but for the second piece of code, `s` remains reversed. I am not sure what is happening here
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The first method *never* changes the original `s` argument, as it slices it (using `s[0]` and `s[1:]`), thus making copies (and when you're calling `s.append(temp)`, `s` is already a copy)

The second method keeps changing the original `s` argument (with `s.pop()` and `s.insert()`)

If you want to avoid that the second method changes the original argument, create a wrapper method that creates a copy beforehand (which also avoids showing the auxiliary index argument)

```
def reverse(s):
    def internal_reverse(s, index):
        if index >= len(s) or len(s) == 0:
            return
        internal_reverse(s, index + 1)
        s.insert((len(s) - 1 - index), s.pop())

    s2 = s[:] # s[:] is a way to copy the input
    internal_reverse(s2, 0)  
    return s2
```

Comment: Thats right! But i thought "s.append(temp)" will actually edit the list by inserting temp to it?

Comment: Sorry i did not get that. Has already changes as in? Could you please elaborate

Comment: @pks the call to `internal_reverse` passes a copy of `s` (the `s[:]` part)

Comment: ah just saw your edited answer. So slice creates a copy and at the point its already sliced. Appending happens to the copy and not the original list. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @pks you may want to read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: thanks @brunodesthuilliers the return part was missing. too sure of myself => no test/test with mental interpretor => mistake.